# Proving $\lim_{→0}1/(3-x)=1/3$ with $\epsilon-\delta$ definition

Tags: real-analysis

I wanted to check if this is correct, it seems trivial I know but i'm trying to make sure because i've my final coming up in two days.

**Problem:** $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{3-x}= \frac{1}{3}$$

$(\forall\varepsilon\gt 0)(\exists\delta\gt 0)$ s. t. $0\lt |x-0|\lt \delta\implies\left\lvert \frac{1}{3-x}-\frac{1}{3}\right\rvert\lt\varepsilon$ .Now,
$$
|1/3-x - 1/3| = |3-(3-x)/3(3-x)| = |3-3+x/ 3(3-x)| = |x /3(3-x)|
$$
≤ 1/3|x /(-x)| ≤ 1/3|1| = 1/3

Comment: Choose $\delta=\epsilon$? Then $|x|<\delta$ implies $|1/3-x-1/3|=|-x|=|x|<\delta=\epsilon$

Comment: What you have done is wrong. You have to  get $< \epsilon$ at the end, not $<\frac 1 3$.

Comment: I'm not sure whether you meant $(1/3)-x$ of $1/(3-x)$, so I made a guess.

Comment: Raydiiii, you have a big problem, $\frac{1}{3-x}=1/(3-x)\ne (1/3-x)$

Comment: If you're going to post here regularly, ray, you should learn how to format mathematics here. There is help available via the Help menu. Also, if you want to be sure that I see a comment, you have to include @Gerry in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proof that $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{3-x}=\frac{1}{3}$.

Suppose $0<|x-0|<\delta$. (i)

Then we have

$3-\delta<3-x<3+\delta$. (ii)

We can assume $\delta$ is small (say $\delta \leq 2$) such that $3-\delta > 0$ and thus $3-x > 0$ (also note that $3+\delta>0$). This in mind, we can safely take the reciprocal of (ii) and obtain:

$\frac{1}{3+\delta}<\frac{1}{3-x}<\frac{1}{3-\delta}$.

As all of these values are positive,

$\frac{1}{3+\delta}<\frac{1}{|3-x|}<\frac{1}{3-\delta}$. (iii)

Then we have $|\frac{1}{3-x}-\frac{1}{3}|=\frac{|x-0|}{3}\frac{1}{|3-x|}<\frac{\delta}{3(3-\delta)}$ (refer to (i) and (iii)). Isolating $\delta$ in $\frac{\delta}{3(3-\delta)}=\epsilon$, we find that $\delta=\frac{9\epsilon}{1+3\epsilon}$. Clearly this will be positive for $\epsilon>0$. So an appropriate choice of $\delta$ is $\delta=\text{min}\bigg\{ 2, \frac{9\epsilon}{1+3\epsilon}\bigg\}$. This completes the proof.

Comment: This is a "solution-varification" question, which means the author is asking to verify his solution/point out his mistake, not for a new answer.

Comment: @Jephph thank you so much! when I tried again I did the same steps I took |x-0| and bounded it to <2 and then multiplied by 1/3 so |x|1/3 was bounded by 2/3 then didn't know what to do with |1/(3(3-x))| to complete it. thanks again